# When offset is commited in Spring Kafka

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I read that since version 2.3 of Spring Kafka *enable.auto.commit* is **false** by default because Kafka's native implementation of autocommiting mechanism is based on time scheduling, which is quite inconvenient. Instead of it Spring Kafka offers a commiting mechanism, bounded to record processing, i.e. you can choose BATCH, RECORD, MANUAL, etc. for AckMode.
So, the question is: for example, default AckMode is BATCH. When is the offset commited? Before passing a batch to a @KafkaListener handler method or after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See JavaDocs of the `ContainerProperties`:

```
/**
 * The ack mode to use when auto ack (in the configuration properties) is false.
 * <ul>
 * <li>RECORD: Commit the offset after each record has been processed by the
 * listener.</li>
 * <li>BATCH: Commit the offsets for each batch of records received from the consumer
 * when they all have been processed by the listener</li>
 * <li>TIME: Commit pending offsets after {@link #setAckTime(long) ackTime} number of
 * milliseconds; (should be greater than
 * {@code #setPollTimeout(long) pollTimeout}.</li>
 * <li>COUNT: Commit pending offsets after at least {@link #setAckCount(int) ackCount}
 * number of records have been processed</li>
 * <li>COUNT_TIME: Commit pending offsets after {@link #setAckTime(long) ackTime}
 * number of milliseconds or at least {@link #setAckCount(int) ackCount} number of
 * records have been processed</li>
 * <li>MANUAL: Listener is responsible for acking - use a
 * {@link org.springframework.kafka.listener.AcknowledgingMessageListener}. Acks will
 * be queued and offsets will be committed when all the records returned by the
 * previous poll have been processed by the listener.</li>
 * <li>MANUAL_IMMDEDIATE: Listener is responsible for acking - use a
 * {@link org.springframework.kafka.listener.AcknowledgingMessageListener}. The commit
 * will be performed immediately if the {@code Acknowledgment} is acknowledged on the
 * calling consumer thread. Otherwise, the acks will be queued and offsets will be
 * committed when all the records returned by the previous poll have been processed by
 * the listener. Results will be indeterminate if you sometimes acknowledge on the
 * calling thread and sometimes not.</li>
 * </ul>
 */
private AckMode ackMode = AckMode.BATCH;
```

And also official Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#committing-offsets

Comment: reading for BATCH: "...whan the all have been processed by the listener" - does it imply than offset will be commited only for **successful** processing without throwing exceptions? Or this behavior is controlled by error handlers?

Comment: If no error handler provided, then no commits, otherwise you are right: the commit depends on the error handling configuration. See more in docs about error handling: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#default-eh